# Java, MySQL method for returning ambiguous ResultSet as an ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm working on an assignment but am confused by the wording of this task:

"Add a method named getData that accepts an SQLstring and the number of fields.
getData should perform the query that was passed in, then convert the ResultSet into a simple 2-d ArrayList."

Here is what I have so far...

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getData(String sqlString, int numFields){
    Statement stmnt= this.conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sqlString);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ary = new ArrayList();
    int row = 0;
    while (rs.next()){ // Get next row
        for (int i = 1; i <= numFields; i++) { // each column
            ary[row][i-1] = rs.getString(i);
        }
        row++;
    }
    return ary;
}
```

I'm getting an error `error: array required, but ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> found`

```
ary[row][i-1] = rs.getString(i);
   ^
```

Thank you in advance for your help and for reading.

EDIT: I believe this is the final/correct/working version, thanks to the answers provided by other awesome users :) now jGrasp is just yelling at me about catching exceptions. I appreciate the help!!!

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getData(String sqlString, int numFields){
    Statement stmnt= this.conn.createStatement();

    ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sqlString);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ary = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()){   // Get next row
        ArrayList<String> columnsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numFields; i++) { // each column
            columnsList.add(rs.getString(i));
            // Add the list of columns to our list of rows
            ary.add(columnsList);
        }
    }
    return ary;
}
```

Comment: a 2D ArrayList would look like `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`, not `ArrayList[][]`

Comment: @Kartik thank you! I updated the question to reflect your suggestion. Still coming up with this weird issue though with regard to setting the arraylist `ary`. I have never worked with multi-dimensional arraylists before so I apologize if this is simple and I'm missing the obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `get()` method to get the element at a particular index from an ArrayList. You can't use [] to get the element at a particular index, in an arraylist. Its possible only for arrays and your resultSet is not an array, but an ArrayList.
You can add to arraylist instead of array as below,

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> ary = new ArrayList();
    int row = 0;
    while (rs.next()){ // Get next row
    ArrayList<String> columns = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= numFields; i++) { // each column
            columns.add(rs.getString(i));
        }
        ary.add(columns)
  }
```

And thet use `get()` method on list to retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a 2D `ArrayList` as being a "list of lists." So as Kartik mentioned in the comments, you would declare it like this:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rows = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now that you have your base `List`, you can create and add new ones to that base list:

```
while (rs.next()){   // Get next row
    ArrayList<String> columnsList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= numFields; i++) { // each column
        columnsList.add(rs.getString(i));
        // Add the list of columns to our list of rows
        rows.add(columnsList);
    }
}
return rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this trivially using [Apache DbUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/examples.html):

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> getData(String sqlString, int numFields){ // numFields unnecessary
    QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner();
    List ret = new ArrayList();
    ret.addAll(run.query(conn, sqlString));
    DbUtils.close(conn);
    return ret;
}
```